# Checking the color of the animation on a region in Raphael JS

Tags: javascript, raphael

First of all,
here is a link to the JS fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/v1tcx2cz/5/

And here is the relevant section of code:

```
for (var i in aus) {

(function(st) {

st.node.state = 0;


st.node.onclick = function() {

  if (this.state == 0) {
    this.state = 1;
    st.animate({
      fill: color,
      stroke: "#fff"
    }, 100); //color at moment of click when colored; should be just var color
  } else {
    this.state = 0;
    st.animate({
      fill: color,
      stroke: "#fff"
    }, 100);
  }
};
  })(aus[i]);

  }
```

I was wondering how I could add a function so that, by clicking the button labeled "check coloring", I could see if the hexagons were colored correctly, i.e. no two adjacent hexagons are colored the same. I commented out my attempt as it made the code not work.

I'm not quite sure how to approach this as the click function colors the region a certain color but I do not know how to access the chosen color for the checking function.

Comment: I think you want attr('fill') rather than animate('fill') when comparing in the commented out code.

Comment: @Ian It still doesn't work... Is it to do with my placement of the check function inside the for loop? Perhaps that is the wrong place to put it?

Comment: There's lots of other coding errors is probably why, and it's not really clear what you are trying to do. Firstly you need to get the scope of check() right. Also you need to use an array rather than an object, if you want to loop over them like an array. Example https://jsfiddle.net/v1tcx2cz/8/

Comment: @Ian hey its been 5 years and what I was working on at the time is long done and over with but I just wanted to let you know that your comments really helped me get it done at the time lol better late than never I guess

Comment: Hah no problem, great it helped, thats what SO is for :).